# Python: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, list, tuples, typeerror

I get a TypeError and I don't understand why. The error is at `c = t[i][0]` (according to the debugger). I have 3 char groups(lists): `g1`, `g2` and `g3` and I'm trying to change the char's index by substracting the key's `k1`, `k2` or `k3` from the index. What I'm using now for testing:

```
text = 'abcd'

l_text = [('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 3)]

k1, k2, k3 = 2, 3, 1
```

And this is the code:

```
def rotate_left(text, l_text, k1, k2, k3):
    i = 0
    newstr = [None]*len(text)
    for t in l_text: # t = tuple
        c = t[i][0] 
        if c in g1: # c = char
            l = int(l_text[i][1]) # l = index of the char in the list
            if l - k1 < 0:
                newstr[l%len(text)-k1] = l_text[i][0]
            else:
                newstr[l-k1] = l_text[i][0]
        elif c in g2:
            l = l_text[i][1] # l = index of the char in the list
            if l - k1 < 0:
                newstr[l%len(text)-k2] = l_text[i][0]
            else:
                newstr[l-k2] = l_text[i][0]
        else:
            l = l_text[i][1] # l = index of the char in the list
            if l - k1 < 0:
                newstr[l%len(text)-k3] = l_text[i][0]
            else:
                newstr[l-k3] = l_text[i][0]
        i += 1
    return newstr
```

Can someone explain me why do I get this error and how do I fix it? It's not like I'm using an `int` type there. The debugger shows it's a str type and it breaks after the 2nd iteration.

PS google didn't help
PPS I know there is too much repetition in the code. I did it to see in the debugger what's happening.

UPDATE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/hometriplerotatie.py", line 56, in <module>
    print(codeer('abcd', 2, 3, 1))
  File "/home/triplerotatie.py", line 47, in codeer
    text = rotate_left(text, l_text, k1, k2, k3)
  File "/home/triplerotatie.py", line 9, in rotate_left
    c = t[i][0] 
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: How're you calling this?

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace?

Comment: On which line does this yield a type error ? Could you post the whole message ?

Comment: this is a function I call within another function, edited the post

Comment: When `i == 1` you will be trying to index the integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are indexing into each *individual* tuple:

```
c = t[i][0]
```

`i` starts out as `0`, but you increment it each loop iteration:

```
i += 1
```

The `for` loop is binding `t` to each individual tuple from `l_text`, so first `t` is bound to `('a', 0)`, then to `('b', 1)`, etc.

So first you are looking at `('a', 0)[0][0]` which is `'a'[0]` which is `'a'`. The next iteration you look at `('b', 1)[1][0]` which is `1[0]` which raises your exception, because integers are not sequences.

You need to remove the `i`; you do *not* need to keep a running index here as the `for t in l_text:` is already giving you *each individual tuple*.

Comment: I feel so dumb now for not seeing this. Thx for the help.

Comment: @Fizunik: Debuggers are all fine & well, but strategically placed print statements can be handy to track down stuff like this.

Answer (score 3):

The error is here:

```
l_text = [('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 3)]

...

for t in l_text: # t = tuple
    # t is a tuple of 2 items: ('a', 0)
    c = t[i][0] # Breaks when i == 1
```

I think you want:

```
c = t[0]
```

It doesn't break the first time round the loop because when `i == 0`, `t[i]` is `'a'` and then `t[i][0]` is also `'a'`.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the index part wrong. Your tuple is 1 dimensional, so you cant use a 2-D array subscript notation.
Assuming that

```
t = ('a',0)
```

you should use `t[0]` or `t[1]` to access `a` and `0` respectively.

Hope it helps.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that t is a tuple, you access the elements in a tuple that like a list. Currently you acces the elements like a 2D list which would, given your lists result in trying to indexing a char.

```
for t in l_text: # t = tuple
    c = t[i][0]
```

should be changed to

```
for t in l_text: # t = tuple
    c = t[0]
```